# Can I approve an Apple Family purchase request without an iDevice?

Tags: ios-appstore, family-sharing

My 12-year-old daughter has an iPhone and wants to install an app. I don't have any Apple devices except an iPod classic. I have an Apple ID because I use iTunes on my PC. How can I approve my daughter's purchase requests?

Comment: You can temporarily make someone else (who has an iPod touch, iPhone, or Mac) an approver to approve this purchase.  Do you know someone who can do that?